# emacs Dired find previous match

Tags: emacs

I mark up a bunch of files in dired

then hit `A` to search through them for a reg-exp

from there its `M-,` to move through to the next match

how do I move back though to the last match?

i.e. whats the opposite of `M-,` in this instance

I know you can do this but I cannot find anything in the documentation *anywhere*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think dired/tags will do that as is.

The function you're invoking with <kbd>M-,</kbd>is `tags-loop-continue,`which appears to be wired to ultimately use `re-search-forward`only. These two functions are defined in `etags.el` if you want to take a look, but there doesn't seem to be anything like a`tags-loop-goback`function or equivalent.

However, [Icicles](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) can apparently do what you want, as indicated in [this discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2008-02/msg00444.html) of a question identical to yours, on the gnu-emacs-help mailing list.

Comment: thansk for the help - i could have sworn i found a keyboard shortcut that allowed yu to step back as well as forward when searching like this - i'll have a check of my notes tomorrow and report back with any findings

Comment: Yeah, seems there would be. If you don't want to use Icicles, I don't think it would be too hard to write functions that would use re-search-backward, using tags-loop-continue and tags-search as templates.